# Unable to connect to Cloud SQL from Google App Engine database

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am unable to connect to Cloud SQL from Google App Engine. I am not sure what the problem is but I came across a note from an instruction stating this is a performance Cloud SQL in alpha stage and connection from Google App Engine are not excepted. Is this the problem I am unable to connect to Cloud SQL? Can anyone explain me the the note? The screenshot of the note is below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting from App Engine is not yet supported for Second Generation instances. You will need to create a First Generation instance if you must connect from App Engine.

Comment: Hi, I created first generation cloud SQL instance but I am still unable to connect to the SQL from appengine

Comment: Can you replace jdbc:google:mysql://canberra-trail-pass-db?user=root with jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:canberra-trail-pass-db?user=root and try again? It looks like there's a problem with the sample code.

Comment: A fix for the code sample should be releases by EOD December 17th. Sorry for the inconvenience.